# not getting all images when passing images data to imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uiimageview

I am parsing xml image urls to `imageview` in `detailviewcontroller` but I passed the images through the `shareddelegate`.but when i click on the `tableviewcell` only few images occure in `detailviewcontroller`.

```
imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharedDelegate.imagObj]]];
```

the above code I wrote in `detailviewcontroller`

```
AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
sharedDelegate.imagObj = [Imagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I wrote this code in tableview `didselectrow` method.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're using this "sharedDelegate" to hold (and pass) information for/to different parts of the program.  That's a poor way to design the app.  Make the data local to the master's model, and pass data using view controller properties, instead of with global "delegates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a image property in DetailViewController

And from tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. call the segue

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailSegue" sender:indexpath];
```

and set it from

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"])
    {
        DetailViewController *dc = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        dc.image = [imagesarray objectAtIndex:sender.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: i use xib.and i have issue on xml parsing  i have a tag like <media:thumbnail url="http://www.cinejosh.com/telugu/newsimg/sukumar-ntr-b_v_-1433151973-1.jpg"/> for that i use the attributeddict object and get the image urls and i didnot write code for didendelement so i have one isssue image array once again called so how to solve this

Comment: if you are using .xib instead of storyboard approach. You can initiate  .xib in didSelect method and pass appropriate object.

Comment: by using shareddelegate i pass but i got this issue when i write in second comment

Answer (score 2):

It would make your code easier to read and maintain, if you pass the data to your detailViewController in a property.

This will help detailViewController to be more self-contained, and limit what it can mutate.

Add a property to your DetailViewController for the data you want to pass.  It sounds like you want to pass an array of image URLs, so add an array property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
```

In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, set the DetailViewController's passed images to the values associated with the selected row:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)__unused sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.images = ...;
    }
}
```

You don't need to have a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, if you create a push segue from a tableViewCell to DetailViewController within Storyboard.  Give the segue an identifier (such as "showDetail").  Then in prepareForSegue, you pass the necessary data, as mentioned.

Comment: i use xib files so how can i able to use the prepare segue

Comment: If you are not using Storyboard, you won't be able to use segues (which handle a lot of things for you).  You should pass the array of image URLs to the detail from the master's `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: i am trying use global variables but it give error mach o link error.

Comment: Don't use global variables.  It's a bad way to design your app.  They're available to everything.   Anything can affect/change them.  But post your error, and we'll see if it's related to this question.  Otherwise, you should ask a new question. :)

Comment: i use shareddelegate to pass the data in the above question i will write and when i click on tableviewcells some images occur and some is not occur and one more issue is when i click on the tableviewcell it move to detail and when it is back it give the imagearray count double like 20 to 40 40 to 60 like

Comment: Yes.  That is because the way you currently wrote it, detailViewController is mutating (adding images to) the global data.  That probably wasn't what you meant to happen :)  The detail view controller shouldn't affect the master's data.  That's why data shouldn't be global, so one part of the program doesn't affect another part.